# Convergence of a sequence Proof

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Is the sequence given by $a_1= 1 , a_2= 1$ and $a_{n+2}= \frac{1+a_{n+1}}{a_n}$ convergent? Prove your conclusion.

Note: I am under the impression that the sequence does not converge given that is doesn't seem to be eventually increasing or eventually decreasing. Nevertheless, I am struggling to find an approach to prove this idea.

Comment: Did you calculate the first few terms of this sequence?

Comment: $a_1 = 1$, $a_2 = 1$, $a_3 = 2$, $a_4 = 3$, $a_5 = 2$, $a_6 = 1$, $a_7 = 1$, $a_8 = 2$, $a_9 = 3$, $a_{10} = 2, \ldots.$
What kind of pattern are you noticing? Now prove the pattern is true using induction.

Comment: Every 5 terms cycles through 1,1,2,3,2. Thank you for this insight. It clarifies this question a lot for me.

Comment: If that's the case, take any $L\in \mathbb R$ and prove that it cannot be the limit of $a_n$, so it is not convergent. Alternatively, you may prove that the sequence is not Cauchy (which is arguably easier).

Comment: This is generally how I start when I see these kinds of problems.

Answer (score 0):

we can use contradiction.Let l be a limit of $a_n$ that means

$\forall$ x>0 $\exists$ N: n>N $\Rightarrow$ |$a_n$-l|<x

we also know that for all natural number k>0 $a_k$=$a_{k+5}$

and $a_{5k+1}$=$a_{5k+2}$=1 $a_{5k+3}$=$a_{5k+5}$=2 $a_{5k+4}$=3

let $x=1/2$ so there exists $5k+2>N$ |$a_{5k+2}$-l|<$1/2$

$5k+3>5k+2>N$ $\Rightarrow$ |$a_{5k+3}-l$|< $1/2$ but |$a_{5k+2}$-l|=|1-l|< $1/2$

$1/2<l<3/2$ but also |$a_{5k+3}-l$|=|2-l|<$1/2$ which means $3/2<l<5/2$

contradiction